# Not connecting a docker container with a postgresql database to a container with a spring backend application

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I was sent a backend project so that I could run it locally on my computer. I was also sent two docker files and a docker-compose file. As I understand it, in one docker file the database is initialized, and in the second the backend application, in the docker-compose file they connect to each other. Images are collected and run without problems, but there is no connection between them. I clarify that I work on Ubuntu 20.04 OS. Everything starts on Windows if you remove the creation of the pj_network subnet from docker-compose.

That's Dockerfile for backend-app:

```
# Use an official Maven image as the base image
FROM maven:latest as build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Maven project files (pom.xml) into the container
COPY pom.xml .

# Download the project dependencies (only if pom.xml changed)
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY src/ ./src/

# Build the Maven project
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

# Use a smaller and more lightweight base image to run the application
FROM openjdk:17

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app
COPY .env /app/.env

# Copy the built artifact from the previous stage into the container
COPY --from=build /app/target/taskmanager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
# Command to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

That's Dockerfile2 for database:

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5432
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB=test
COPY src/main/resources/database/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

That's docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=test'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - pj_network

  jp2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - pj_network

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

networks:
  pj_network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db:
```

That's application.properties:

```
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# liquibase configuration
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/database/changelog/changelog.yaml

# Mail Configuration
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username={mail username}
spring.mail.password=ic{mail password}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

# Server config
server-address=194.85.169.95
server-port=9226

# Date and Time patterns
date.pattern=dd.MM.yyyy
dateTime.pattern=dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
```

That's my backend-app container logs:

```
2023-10-04T13:44:19.104Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] r.v.taskmanager.TaskManagerApplication   : Starting TaskManagerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.2 with PID 1 (/app/app.jar started by root in /app)

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:19.109Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] r.v.taskmanager.TaskManagerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:20.684Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:20.864Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 167 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:21.848Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:21.866Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:21.867Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:21.992Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:21.996Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2805 ms

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:22.181Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

jp2_1  | 2023-10-04T13:44:23.470Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

jp2_1  | 

jp2_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

jp2_1  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]

jp2_1  |    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0

jp2_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]

jp2_1  |    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]

jp2_1  |    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
```

I tried to change address in application.properties, try to connect to local database, but it doesn't work too

UPD:
That's info about my subnet:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "vibelab-project-main_pj_network",
        "Id": "130174aaec4ed030497e1b19e8ad48e0d28e103717c8d1d82eb26ebc4bc9b2b3",
        "Created": "2023-10-04T18:01:07.268785188+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "a45d2acd475905ecbff70b9e261d68eda9b0033323750641f016602964443a25": {
                "Name": "vibelab-project-main_jp2_1",
                "EndpointID": "4a30fa49a68db665f0bc7d9c285abf28f6cb7366c12754d58086f2c04ffa99ac",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c59e0cd8bff3631d1609531b9a2a821947ec4e26c79984ec19af1a6b0269198d": {
                "Name": "vibelab-project-main_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "f2741c3edb36f5e7a9a2ed9970e0becf9ca3784eb02374ea593f35a7d17808ce",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "pj_network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "vibelab-project-main",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.1"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work?  (Is the application starting up before the database initialization is complete?)

Comment: You've named your database container `db`, but you've used a different host name `postgres` in the `spring.datasource.url` property.  I might set a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable in the Compose setup to use the Compose-specific host name.

Comment: @DavidMaze, with db it doesn't work too.A colleague said that he was able to fix the error by changing 'db' to 'postgres'

Comment: If i try to run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, console displays 
`vibelab-project-main_db_1 is up-to-date
vibelab-project-main_jp2_1 is up-to-date`